# Importing a type from node_modules in typescript directly - is this normal?

Tags: typescript

I need to import a specific type in TypeScript from a module. It does not seem to export this type if I import the module. The only way how I want to fix this is to directly import it from the right file in node_modules. Is this the way to go?

I thus have

```js
import { SomeType } from "../../node_modules/some_module/some_file"
```

to import this type. This does not seem optimal to me as if this file changes I should import some other file (which thus mean I have to fix the version of the imported module).

Comment: Why can't you do it `... from "some_module/some_file"`? What happens? What *are* that module and file?

Comment: This module only exports it internally; it does not export it if you import the entire module.